# Compare 2 cells to highlight third cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two cells in Excel with time data in them which I want to compare. Then based on the result I want the third cell which contains the sum total of 4 cells to turn green or red.

```
A
B
C
D Total
E Time             
F      > Want to compare those two to change the total color
G Time
```

Comment: And you are not aware of *conditional formatting* in Excel or have  a problem applying it?

Answer (score 1):

Under the home tab, select "conditional formatting" and then "New Rule" while positioned on the cell you want the color to change. Select the "Use Formula to determine which cell to format" option, and type the condition that must be met for it to turn Red (e.g. `=OR(A1="",B1="")`). Repeat the process and this time type the condition that must be met for it to turn Green (e.g. `=A1>=B1`).

Under the Conditional Formatting options you can also select manage rules and provide a Hierarchy for these conditions (If you need this).